# Use case for parts and repairs

Tags: picklist, junction-object

I have a use case that requires calculating "repair costs" on Maintenance Request Objects (I am calling it MR 2). The partname and partcost are fields in a Parts Object.  There are about 100 different parts in the parts object. The scenario is that workers complete maintenance requests and select parts that were used in the repair.  Parts have costs that are added up to fill a "Parts cost" field on the Maintenance Object. The question is how to go about this? Does it require custom code?

I tried initially to load custom settings with parts data and tried to use this in a formula field on MR 2. -- you cannot reference the fields in custom settings.  I also tried to create a junction object (J.O.)  "Parts for Repair" between MR 2 and Parts obj, but when I tried to enter data for the J.O., it wouldn't let me select the parts (see image below).  I am looking for a broad overview type answer. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Hi there! Can you add the formula you're using to a code block in the question? My immediate thought is that a formula field is the way to go here as well.

Comment: No code block at present, trying to do it via customization

Answer (score 0):

I would indeed use a junction object, which is a child of an MR2 object and which has a relationship with a parts object. For each part that is needed in an MR2, you create a junction object. Also create a formula field in the junction object that is the cost of the referenced part. Than, because the junction object is a child of MR2, you can create a roll-up summary field in MR2 for the total repair costs.

This does not require any custom code.

Comment: I had a similar set up with three objects -- Maintenance Request2 (or MR 2), Parts for Repair (J.O.) and Part 2;  There are two problems 1) When entering records how to get the J.O. to show the list of parts from Part2 so I can select which part was used in the Maintenance Request.  2) When I want the corresponding cost of the selected part to be entered into the J.O. i.e. J.O part cost, what formula should I use?  There doesn't seem any way to refer to fields in other objects inside the formula editor.

Comment: As for the selection of parts: you can enter a part of the name in the field, then search for it. As for referring to fields in other objects, if you have a relationship to them, you can refer to them with the __r notation, but they are also selectable via the formula constructor. If you don't understand this, then I have misunderstood your question or you should learn more about formulas and relationships between objects.

Comment: Thanks for responding, the parts used in a repair (Maintenance Request 2) are selected by a technician.  Not added already.  When we go to the J.O. and try to enter part#, it doesn't allow us (see image above), you cannot even enter part of the name.  So I made part# a formula field, but it requires selection by ID and this defeats the use case.  The second problem I encountered was in the total parts cost in the rollup summary field in MR2.  I couldn't figure out how to add only the part costs for a certain repair e.g. have repair records MR repair1, MR repair2...  How to sum only MR repair2?